# Username/handle system using Python - TCP/IP chat client

Tags: python, tcp, client

Here is my server code.

```js
# chat_server.py
 
import sys, socket, select

HOST = '' 
SOCKET_LIST = []
RECV_BUFFER = 4096 
PORT = 9009

def chat_server():

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)
 
    # add server socket object to the list of readable connections
    SOCKET_LIST.append(server_socket)
 
    print "Chat server started on port " + str(PORT)
 
    while 1:

        # get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
        # 4th arg, time_out  = 0 : poll and never block
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST,[],[],0)
      
        for sock in ready_to_read:
            # a new connection request recieved
            if sock == server_socket: 
                sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
                SOCKET_LIST.append(sockfd)
                print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr
                 
                broadcast(server_socket, sockfd, "[%s:%s] entered our chatting room\n" % addr)
             
            # a message from a client, not a new connection
            else:
                # process data recieved from client, 
                try:
                    # receiving data from the socket.
                    data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    if data:
                        # there is something in the socket
                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "\r" + '[' + str(sock.getpeername()) + '] ' + data)  
                    else:
                        # remove the socket that's broken    
                        if sock in SOCKET_LIST:
                            SOCKET_LIST.remove(sock)

                        # at this stage, no data means probably the connection has been broken
                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr) 

                # exception 
                except:
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)
                    continue

    server_socket.close()
    
# broadcast chat messages to all connected clients
def broadcast (server_socket, sock, message):
    for socket in SOCKET_LIST:
        # send the message only to peer
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock :
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except :
                # broken socket connection
                socket.close()
                # broken socket, remove it
                if socket in SOCKET_LIST:
                    SOCKET_LIST.remove(socket)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.exit(chat_server())
```

Here is my client code.

```js
# chat_client.py

import sys, socket, select
 
def chat_client():
    if(len(sys.argv) < 3) :
        print 'Usage : python chat_client.py hostname port'
        sys.exit()

    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])
     
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)
     
    # connect to remote host
    try :
        s.connect((host, port))
    except :
        print 'Unable to connect'
        sys.exit()
     
    # TEST
    person = raw_input ('Please enter your username: ')
    print 'Connected to remote host. You can start sending messages.'
    sys.stdout.write( person + '[Me]: ' ); sys.stdout.flush()
     
    while 1:
        socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]
         
        # Get the list sockets which are readable
        read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])
         
        for sock in read_sockets:            
            if sock == s:
                # incoming message from remote server, s
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if not data :
                    print '\nDisconnected from chat server'
                    sys.exit()
                else :
                    #print data
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    sys.stdout.write( person + '[Me]: '); sys.stdout.flush()     
            
            else :
                # user entered a message
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()
                s.send(msg)
                sys.stdout.write( person + '[Me]: '); sys.stdout.flush() 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.exit(chat_client())
```

I'm currently trying to work on adding sort of a "handle" system into the chat client. If you were to run this code, you'll notice that the handle you choose is only displayed on your client, and not anybody else's. I've done hours of research already, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to have a client's chosen handle displayed onto other clients.

I'm still relatively new to Python, and especially new to TCP/IP programming. Any help, advice, and constructive criticism will be welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on the server or the client side

### Server side

To implement it server side, you need to maintain some kind of mapping in the server between client sockets and handles, so that when you broadcast a message from a socket, you can retrieve its handle and prepend it to the message before sending.

In order to know the handle of the clients, they can send it to the server as the first message when they connect. The server will interpret this first message as the handle, and store it mapping it to the socket from what it has been received.

The advantage of this approach is that the server can validate the handle before it accepts it from the clients, and if it is already in use, reject the handle or abort the connection. Also, the clients cannot fake their handle later in the conversation, as it is the server that sends them.

### Client side

This is the easiest implementation, as you only need to modify the client and prepend the handle before sending each message.

```
            # user entered a message
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            s.send(person + ": " + msg)
            sys.stdout.write( person + '[Me]: '); sys.stdout.flush()
```

The drawbacks of this approach are that a malicious client can fake the handle to pretend to be another person, and that two clients can have the same handle at the same time, making them indistinguishable from each other.